# Add android project to another project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have android project A and project B both configured in android studio. Now i want to and whole project B to project A as dependency. then in project A i want to start a activity in project B so is it possible and more importantly how?!

Project B contains all android_manifest, graidle confings, proguard ruls, etc.

If it's not possible to add project as dependency what is the minimal way add content of project B (more than 200 files, drawables, dimens, etc.) in project A in a separate place so it don't messes up my project!

Comment: Create project as a library project and apply it to other one..!!

Comment: Have you tried adding a new module? File>New>Import Module?

Answer (score 5):

You can add *project B* as dependency. For that your *project B* must be a *library* project. You can add a source library project to an application project was like this.

Add a reference to *project B* into `ProjectA/settings.gradle` file

```
include ':projectb'
project(':projectb').projectDir = new File('/pathTo/ProjectB/library')
...
```

Add compile time dependency to *project B* in `ProjectA/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":projectb")
    ...
}
```

Now just re-sync Gradle files changes in Android Studio and it will create all modules required.

You will be able to use Java classes and resources with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open project A in studio. click on File-->New-->Import Module and import B.

Add dependency in A's build.gradle file

Use  intent to start Activity in project B